# Why does Jack Nicholson say "Here's Johnny!" in The Shining when his character is called Jack?

Tags: the-shining

In The Shining, when Jack Torrance has clearly gone mad and is chopping down the bathroom door with an axe to get to his wife, why does Jack Nicholson say "Here's Johnny!" when his character's name is Jack? Is it completely random and showing how he's gone so insane he's just saying random names, or does it have some sort of significance?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That line was ad-libbed by Jack Nicholson as an imitation of Ed McMahon's intro for The Tonight Show.

From [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081505/trivia):

> Jack Nicholson ad-libbed the line "Here's Johnny!" in imitation of
>   announcer Ed McMahon's famous introduction of Johnny Carson on U.S.
>   network NBC-TV's long-running late night television program The
>   Tonight Show Starring Johnny Carson. Stanley Kubrick, who had been
>   living in England since before Carson took over "The Tonight Show,"
>   had no clue what "Here's Johnny!" meant. Carson once used the clip of
>   Nicholson as the introduction to one of his annual anniversary
>   specials.

Comment: Also, Jack is a nickname for John so it fits with his character's name too.

Comment: @tcrosley Really? Jack means John? Now I didn't know that! And I thought Bill for William was already weird! Thanks for this information.

Comment: @tcrosley - Yes, my dad John goes by Jack. It's probably less common nowadays, but it used to be pretty common.

Comment: They called jfk jack sometimes

Comment: Tom Clancy used "Jack" as John Ryan, Sr.'s nickname in his books. Used to be more common, I think, but still valid.

Comment: Another example of the John/Jack - In the village where I grew up, a new breed of dog was named the Jack Russell Terrier, after the local Parson who bred them for hunting. He was called John Russell.

Comment: The scene in "Night of the Living Dead" where zombie Johnny comes walking through the door and grabs Barbara makes me think of this